# Is it possible to show an overlay when a form is submitted (not via Ajax)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, overlay

A bit of background: I am using asp .net MVC and I am **not** allowed to asynchrounously submit the form using JQuery. When the user submits the form it takes a few seconds for the save to happen and then a message is displayed to them. In this time the client wants to show an overlay with an image and a processing label. I was using BlockUI (Jquery plugin) for all overlays but it wont work since I am not posting the form via ajax.

Any ideas on how to show an overlay is much appreciated.

TIA.

Regards,

Raja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tie a overlay to the button click, because you are not using AJAX the form submission will reload the page.

Also, blockUI should not require AJAX.

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $.blockUI();
});
```

Comment: But will it show the overlay until the page comes back (I use PRG pattern)?

Comment: Yes, until the page reloads. Without AJAX there is nothing that can prevent a small gap in page reload.

Comment: Wow that works absolutely fine.....didn't know blockUI will work even if the operation is not asynchronous. Thanks a bunch :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since u are using MVC, am not sure if u are using webforms or controllers.

Please try this,

For webforms, u can use OnClientClick to call a javascript to show the div that has the processing gif image.

For controller pattern, in  onclick event handler before the form is submitted, use javascript/jquery to show the div that has the processing gif image.